# How to implement AsyncTransformer in Jest?

Tags: jestjs, esbuild

I am trying to use jest with the esbuild based project. I tried to use [esbuild-jest-transform](https://github.com/AkifumiSato/esbuild-jest-transform) and [esbuild-jest](https://github.com/aelbore/esbuild-jest) transformers, but in both cases, I got error `Cannot use plugins in synchronous API calls` from esbuild. This makes sense and I tried to implement `AsyncTransformer` instead.

But after switching from `SyncTransformer` to `AsyncTransformer`, I got the following error:

```
● Invalid synchronous transformer module:
      ".../node_modules/esbuild-jest-transform/index.js" specified in the "transform" object of Jest configuration
      must export a `process` function.
```

which implies that it should be implemented in the old way. [Here are more details about it](https://github.com/AkifumiSato/esbuild-jest-transform/issues/7).

Could you please tell, me how to make jest to use `AsyncTransformer` instead of `SyncTransformer`?

I tried to use `import()` as is described in the [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation), but got the same result.

Comment: Using the asynchronous implementation requires syntactic sugar 
`import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'` etc. 
See more details under the this [link](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#js-details)

Comment: @DimiTakis thank you for the answer, but that didn't fix the issue. As I understand, there are two ways of coping with this:

1. Allow using `plugins` in `esbuild` in synchronous mode
2. Allowing running `AsyncTransformer` in jest for CommonJS

Comment: @DimiTakis actually this is the is used in the jest transformer: https://github.com/AkifumiSato/esbuild-jest-transform/blob/ebe5282/index.ts#L3

Comment: @code1n did you end up solving this. I am in the same situation. `async processAsync` doesn't seem to be working even with `.mjs` extension.